# Bootloop on every Ubuntu version

Tags: boot, 16.04, hp, 17.04

After I updated to Ubuntu 16.04.2  or  17.04 the screen turns black and I can't do nothing. Even if I try to install it from a USB driver not even the live CD works. The machine I'm trying to install its a HP Pavilion 15 aw002la. I think it's the Linux kernel version, because in previous version all worked fine.

Comment: I think it's a problem with your graphics driver. Can you login via Ctrl-Alt-F1? Can you run `sudo lshw -C display`?

Comment: When do I have to press that key combination? While installing? @waltinator

Comment: After booting. Ctrl-Alt-F1 will switch you to a non-GUI terminal. Hit Enter, login, then type the command.

Comment: But I can't even access to the log in screen. The screen freezes when the Ubuntu is loading, before the log in screen @waltinator